# How to enable automatic login after registration in Identity Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3

I have just started using `Identity Server 3` and have wired case that user needs to be automatically login to the system as soon the registration is done.

I have tried to follow  many links but I couldn't find any link which resolves the problem.

Please help me getting this done. I have no clue how to do that.

Thanks,
Amod

Answer (score 0):

There are various OWIN environment extension methods that you can use to communicate with IdentityServer from custom code running in the same host and pipeline. Here are the docs: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/owin.html